# TortoiseSVN unified diff to working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, unified-diff

In TortoiseSVN it's possible to view a revision's changes as a unified diff by right clicking it in the revision log, and clicking "show changes as unified diff". But that doesn't let me view *my working copy's changes* as a unified diff. Is it possible to do this somehow?

I also noticed I can right click in Windows Explorer and select *TortoiseSVN->Create patch* which does what I want, but it also saves the diff as a file which I don't want. I just want to *view* the diff.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. In the Commit dialog, one needs to shift-select as many of the files as one wants, then right click and select 'show differences as unified diff'.

Comment: Or, use the 'create patch' command. A patch is nothing more than a unified diff.